# wildfly swarm jdk10 support

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

When I try to switch a wildfly-swarm-2018.4.2 project from jdk9 to jdk10, the startup fails due to a asm classreader exception. As 2018.4.2 and also 2018.5.0 both uses asm 6.0 it seems obvious that jdk10 is not supported.

1. would there be an easy way to replace the asm version by myself? if I just put asm 6.1.1 to the maven dependencies the uberjar is nevertheless built with and depending on asm 6.0
2. how are jdk upgrades planned in the future? as we will receive a new jdk more often now, a quick support in swarm would be great
3. interestingly enough a jdk10 app works with wildfly 11/12, something I could not understand, because the asm version in wildfly 12 is also just 6.0

I really would appreciate some clarifications.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can easily replace the ASM version. Also if there's a `.class` format change, we also depend on Jandex update. For the 2nd/3rd item, I believe the WildFly Swarm Google group would be a more appropriate place to ask.